# Как получить определенный dropDown options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть `selected` c `options`. Опций может быть много, в зависимости от цели.
Как мне получить определенную опцию (допустим, 10-ую по счету)?
Могу получать только первый и последний, а как выбрать по индексу?

Comment: `$('.myselect').find('option').eq(10)`?

Comment: thank you :) for a heklp)

Comment: alert($('#start').find('option').eq(1).html());  вот так ,так как он на входе дает массив обьекта

Comment: Да и он дает только опцию а мне значение надо value

Comment: Ну, стоило тогда указать это в вопросе, мб?

Comment: Да тормазнул...

Comment: ну ты напиши отвик полноценный я тебе пальчик вврх дам)Заодно и другим помощь буэт)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить элемент по порядковому номеру можно через `$(selector).eq(index)`, либо `$('selector:eq(index)')`, где `index` - номер элемента, начиная от `0`. Предпочтительнее первый способ, т.к. легче читать и не нужно манипуляций с конкатенацией строк и чисел(селектора и индекса)

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  var val = $(this).val()*1;
  var option = $('select').find('option').eq(val);
  if(option.val() != undefined){
    $('#out').html(option.val() + '<br/><b>Код команды:</b> $("select").find("option").eq('+val + ')');
    $('#out_html').html(option.html());
    $('select').val(option.val());
  }
});
//$('select')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Option number:</b> <input/><br/>
<select style='margin-top:10px;'>
  <option value='opt_1'>FIRST</option>
  <option value='opt_2'>SECOND</option>
  <option value='opt_3'>THIRD</option>
  <option value='opt_4'>FOURTH</option>
  <option value='opt_5'>FIFTH</option>
 </select><br/>
<b>Option value:</b> <span id='out'></span><br/>
<b>Option html:</b> <span id='out_html'></span>
```

Comment: СПасибоооооо!))З

Answer (score 1):

На javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myselect option')[10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если список опций имеет вот такой вид:

```
<select name="" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

То проблему задачу решить вот так:

*чистый JS:*

```
    document.getElementById('select').options[9].value // получение значения 10-го элемента
    document.getElementById('select').options[9].text // получение текста 10-го элемента
```

*jQuery:*

```
    $('#select option:nth-child(10)').val() // получение значения 10-го элемента
    $('#select option:eq(9)').val() // получение значения 10-го элемента
    $('#select option').eq(9).val() // получение значения 10-го элемента
    // текст получаем аналогично через метод .text()
```

Comment: Ваш код не работает поччему то

Comment: js не пашет а jquery все ок!спасибо добрый

Comment: @elik код представлялся для ознакомления, т.к. все варианты были собраны в один